# Choosing a random integer from a list of ranges in Java

Tags: java

I have a list of ranges in Java

```
public class Range {
   private int min, max;
   //constructor, getters, setters go here
}
```

So, a list may look like this

```
ranges = [[3,9], [18,45], [90,112]]
```

And I need to make the following function

```
public int getRandomValueWithinRanges() {
   //returns a value which is contained inside a range inside the ranges ArrayList
}
```

How can I do this? Each value within those ranges should have an equal probability of being chosen, and it should be done efficiently (i.e. making a list of all the values inside the ranges and then choosing randomly from that list is *not* efficient)

Comment: try this - `rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, one approach:

1. Sum up all the ranges (that is, the total number of integers that they span)
2. Pick a random value from `[0-total)`
3. Treat the random value *as an index* and incrementally find which range this index corresponds to
4. Offset the random number based on the range start that contains said index..

Comment: That's possibly the fastest way to do what you want.

Comment: This is the only answer that ensures equal probability for all values. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, choose a random range. Then choose a random integer from the selected random range.

Comment: Correct. Although psts approach would be quicker in the end (but more difficult to implement).

Comment: If I understand the OP's (imprecise) description, then this is not correct.  My reading is that each number should have an equal probability of being returned.  But in this "solution", numbers in small ranges have a higher probability of being returned.

Comment: This does not ensure equal probability, because some ranges are bigger than others.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution depends on whether you can *amortize* the setup cost over a number of calls to `getRandomValueWithinRanges` with *the same* list of ranges.

If you cannot amortize, then @pst's approach is best.

If you can amortize, then there are a variety of ways that you can make the method faster; e.g.

- Build an array list of the elements of all ranges.  This gives the fastest `getRandom...`, but has a large setup time and a large space overhead.
- Build a data structure to speed up the mapping of random indexes (in @pst's solution) to values.

---

It should be noted that a simple selection of a random range and random element in the range is liable to bias the selection of random numbers ... unless you can figure out how to compensate by weighting the range selection or something.